# Concatenate single column from multiple rows into a one column with distinct keywords

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I have a `table` Article  which has one column `keywords` which stores tags or keywords

Sample Data

```
Table Article
------------------------------------------
ID    keywords
------------------------------------------
1     one, two, three
2     four, five, six
3     seven, eight, three
4     one, two, three
5     twenty, hundred, one hundred one, one hundred two, seventy
6     seventy, three, two hundred
```

If I use a CTE query as below then it will concatenate all the keywords column in one row but on other side also gets duplicate row, which is a problem as I we will have 1000's of article with hundreds of similar keywords.

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    stuff(
    (
    select cast(',' as varchar(max)) + lower(Keywords)
    from art_Article a
    for xml path('')
    ), 1, 1, '') AS All_Keywords
FROM
    art_Articles G
ORDER BY
    G.ArticleKeywords ASC;
```

Above query yields follow result as single row

```
---------------------------------------------------
All_Keywords
----------------------------------------------------
one, two, three,four, five, six,seven, eight, three,one, two, three,twenty, hundred, one hundred one, one hundred two, seventy,seventy, three, two hundred
```

It is obvious from the result that it also show duplicate keywords no. of time as it is stored in row. Is their a way I can get duplicate keywords only once?

I would appreciate if some can help me to sort this to get the result as single column with `DISTINCT` keywords only.

Comment: I don't have a SQL server at hands but what about splitting the second column into the single keywords and trying to aggregate those then in the select?

Comment: @DadaDom, I managed to pull it off What i did combined it with a split function & RUN Distinct SELECT statement on it which gave me Unique results

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are going to have to split the data up into rows first, before concatenating it together. This will allow you to get the distinct values when using `FOR XML PATH` to get the final list.

Here is a CTE version of this process:

```
;with cte (id, word, words) as
(
  select id,
    cast(left(keywords, charindex(',',keywords+',')-1) as varchar(50)) word,
         stuff(keywords, 1, charindex(',',keywords+','), '') words
  from article
  union all
  select id,
    cast(left(words, charindex(',',words+',')-1) as varchar(50)) word,
    stuff(words, 1, charindex(',',words+','), '') words
  from cte
  where words > ''
) 
select top 1 
    stuff((select distinct ', '+ rtrim(ltrim(word))
           from cte
           for xml path('')), 1, 1, '') AS All_Keywords
from cte
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7a6d6/13). Which gives the result:

```
|                                                                                                             ALL_KEYWORDS |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  eight, five, four, hundred, one, one hundred one, one hundred two, seven, seventy, six, three, twenty, two, two hundred |
```

Comment: Appreciate it works great, mean while i also managed to find a solution which i have also posted as a solution, I would appreciate your comments on that from performance point of view and i might have thousands or article to works with. I will mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 2):

A correlated subquery should do it:

```
SELECT G.ID,
    stuff(
    (
    select cast(',' as varchar(max)) + lower(Keywords)
    from art_Article a
    where a.id = g.id
    for xml path('')
    ), 1, 1, '') AS All_Keywords
FROM
    art_Articles G
ORDER BY
    G.ArticleKeywords ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the Solution is to combine result with Split function & Run SQL statement with DISTINCT on it. You can further modify this for your needs. I have test & it is working for me. Hope it helps other people.

```
DECLARE @Keywords nvarchar(MAX)
SELECT TOP 1 @Keywords =
    stuff(
    (
    select cast(',' as varchar(max)) + lower(Keywords)
    from Article U
    for xml path('')
    ), 1, 1, '') 
FROM
    Articles G
ORDER BY
    G.ArticleKeywords ASC;

SELECT DISTINCT(VALUE) AS VALUE FROM [uf_SplitKeywords] (',', @Keywords)
```

Split Function Code below

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[uf_SplitKeywords] 
   (  @DELIMITER VARCHAR(5), 
      @LIST      VARCHAR(MAX) 
   ) 
   RETURNS @TABLEOFVALUES TABLE 
      (  ROWID   int IDENTITY(1,1), 
         [VALUE] VARCHAR(MAX) 
      ) 
AS 
   BEGIN
   Declare @Pos int
   While LEN(@List) > 0
      begin
        Select @Pos=CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@List,1)      
        if @Pos>0
           begin
             Insert into @TABLEOFVALUES ([Value]) Values (SubString(@List,1,@Pos -1))
             Select @LIST = STUFF(@List,1,@Pos ,'')
           end
        else  
            begin
            Insert into @TABLEOFVALUES ([Value]) Values (@List)
            Select @LIST =''
            end  
      end
   Return 
   End
```